# Unable to catch `CHECK constraint failed:` error in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 table that has some length constraints on some of its columns.

My PHP code that tries to update a row in this table is something like this:

```
...
try {
  $statement = $db->prepare('UPDATE '.$tname.' SET _blablabla_');
  $statement->bindValue(_blablabla_); // ...
  $result = $statement->execute();
  $status = "Updated! " . $db->LastErrorMsg();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $status = "Error updating! ".$e->getMessage();
}
...
```

I am unable to catch a constraint error in PHP. The above code sets `$status` to `Updated! not an error` while throws the following warning message to web server's log:

```
PHP Warning:  SQLite3Stmt::execute(): Unable to execute statement: CHECK constraint failed: length(&quot;data&quot;) &lt;= 102400 in ... on line 42
```

Here line 42 is the `execute` function. How can I catch the `CHECK constraint failed` error into my `$status` variable?

Note that the `UPDATE` SQL statement does not update the table (as expected); but the `execute` function seems to return normally.

---

**Update:** I tested the `$result` variable and it is *false* after a constraint error is received. However, I do not want this error to be logged, but instead I want a string representation of the message to be received by the PHP application.

Comment: It's a warning, not an exception. You need to check the value of `$result`. It will be `true` if the query succeeded, `false` if it got an error.

Comment: Instead of using SQLite directly, consider using PDO.

Comment: If you don't want warnings to be logged use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING)`

Comment: Can you show what class the $db variable is?

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite3 php module has [exceptions disabled by default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.enableexceptions.php).

You have to enable them after creating your `db` object:

```
$db->enableExceptions(true);
```

If you dont use exceptions, then you can still get the error or warning message:

*For either mode, the error code and message, if any, will be available via SQLite3::lastErrorCode() and SQLite3::lastErrorMsg() respectively.*